# Use of immutable stack

Tags: c#, stack, immutability

I've seen the [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx) announcing the release of a stable version of the [Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable) NuGet package today.

I'm wondering: what would be usage for an immutable stack? I can't find an example or a scenario where that would be useful. Might be my understanding of immutability. If you could shed some light on why this thing might be useful, preferably with a concrete example, this would be nice.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've seen that article. But it doesn't provide a reason why an immutable stack could be useful in some contexts. Once again, that might be my understanding of immutability that is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind this library of collections is to provide collections, that when changed produce new versions of the same collection, where all old versions of the collections are still valid.

It is similar to how version control system works: You can change code, and commit changes to the server, producing a new version of the source tree. In the meantime you can still checkout any previous revision.

For immutable collections, you keep acces to an old version (essentially an immutable snapshot) by keeping a pointer to the collection that will not change.

You could argue that this scenario is less useful for a stack because you probably use a stack to add and retrieve each item exactly once, and also preserving the order. Usually a stack's use is very much tied to code running on a single thread of execution.

But now that I'm typing, I can think of a specific use case if you have a lazy parser that needs to track some state in a stack. You can then save a pointer to the immutable stack in the state it was during the initial parse, without copying, and retrieve it when you parse the deferred work.

Comment: "set of collections is to have collections, that produce new versions of collection, .. all old collections ..." =)

Comment: @MikroDel: Yeah that looked dumb. Like it better now? :)

Answer (score 3):

I love the immutable collections but they often feel like a solution in need of a problem. They can be [unexpectedly slow](https://ayende.com/blog/164739/immutable-collections-performance) due to [how they are implemented](https://ayende.com/blog/164740/immutable-collections-performance-take-ii): they try very hard to use memory efficiently at the cost of making `foreach` loops and indexers much more algorithmically complex. With how plentiful memory is, it can be hard to justify that cost. There's a dearth of information to be found on the web about successful uses of immutable collections (other than [`ImmutableArray<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638264(v=vs.111).aspx)). In an attempt to rectify that, I thought I'd add an answer to this 3+ year old question about a case where I found [`ImmutableStack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467197(v=vs.111).aspx) to be truly useful.

Consider this very basic tree-like structure:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode Parent { get; private set; }
    public List<TreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(TreeNode parent) 
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I've created classes that follow this basic pattern many, many times, and in practice, it's always worked for me. More recently, I've started to do something like this:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public ImmutableStack<TreeNode> NodeStack { get; private set; }
    public ImmutableStack<TreeNode> ParentStack { get { return NodeStack.IsEmpty ? ImmutableStack<TreeNode>.Empty : NodeStack.Pop(); } }
    public TreeNode Parent { get { return ParentStack.IsEmpty ? null : ParentStack.Peek(); } }

    public ImmutableArray<TreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            NodeStack = ImmutableStack<TreeNode>.Empty;
        else
            NodeStack = parent.NodeStack.Push(this);
    }
}
```

For a variety of reasons, I've come to prefer storing an `ImmutableStack<T>` of `TreeNode` instances that I can traverse to the root rather than simply a reference to the `Parent` instance.

- `ImmutableStack<T>`'s implementation is basically a linked list. Each instance of `ImmutableStack<T>` is really a node on a linked list. That's why the `ParentStack` property just `Pop`'s the `NodeStack`. `ParentStack` will return the same instance of `ImmutableStack<T>` as `Parent.NodeStack` would.
- If you store a reference to the `Parent` `TreeNode`, it would be easy to create a circular loop that would cause operations such as finding the root node to never terminate, and you'd either get a stack overflow or an infinite loop. An `ImmutableStack<T>`, on the other hand, can be ascended by `Pop`-ing, guaranteeing that it will terminate.

  - The fact that you use a collection (`ImmutableStack<T>`) means that you can prevent circular loops from happening in the first place by simply making sure the `parent` `TreeNode` does not occur twice when constructing the `TreeNode`.

That's just to start with. I think the `ImmutableStack<T>` makes tree operations simpler and safer. You can (safely) use LINQ on it. Want to know if one `TreeNode` is a descendent of another? You could simply do `ParentStack.Any(node => node == otherNode)`

More generally, the `ImmutableStack<T>` class is for any case where you would like a `Stack<T>` that you can guarantee will never be modified, or you need an easy way to get a "snapshot" of a `Stack<T>` but don't want to create create a bunch of copies of that stack. If you have a series of nested steps, you could use an `ImmutableStack<T>` to track progress, and so when a step is completed, it can hand off work to its parent step. Its immutable nature is especially helpful when you're trying to do work in parallel.